# Getting code1 command failed error while installing nodemon

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, nodemon

I am running this `npm i nodemon -D` and getting a command failed error. Please click on the above image to view the error.

I tried deleting package.json, removing node_modules, and installing it again, but the error persists. I have been attempting a bunch of solutions to resolve this issue but I don't know why it gives this error again and again.

[Error image: This error is coming on my VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYons.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by using command `npm config set script-shell cmd`
and then installing nodemon package by `npm install nodemon`

Lastly, don't forget to reverse the changes and set it back to default by using `npm config set script-shell powershell`